# Why Nginx is not rejecting wrong hosts?

Tags: nginx

This is my config:

```
upstream beta {     
  server localhost:49213;
}
server {     
  listen 80;
  server_name beta.example.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://beta;     
  }   
}
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name "";
  return 444;
}
```

When I open `localhost:80` I also see the content of `localhost:49213`. I find it wrong. Nginx should reject all requests that don't have `beta.example.com` in `Host` HTTP header, right? Why it's not happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, here is the answer. The server with an empty `server_name` has to be declared as a "default" one. More details here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name

Nginx, when `Host` HTTP header doesn't match any `server`s, goes into the default one, which is the first, if not specified otherwise. Here is the config that works:

```
upstream beta {     
  server localhost:49213;
}
server {     
  listen 80;
  server_name beta.example.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://beta;     
  }   
}
server {
  listen 80 default_server; # pay attention!
  server_name "";
  return 444;
}
```